# Cannot find xml element using linq query in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-xml, portable-class-library

in an console project I create an XDocument and using linq to get xml elements. See following code. I try to use the same in a portable class library but it does not work. Is there a different between console projects and portable class library by using linq to xml?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
Stream strm = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(strm);

 var de = from el in doc.Descendants("outline")
          select new
          {
               title = (string)el.Element("title")
           };
```

In the following the xml example:

```
<opml version="2.0">
    <head> 
        <title>Outline of Category 41</title> 
        <dateCreated>Tue, 26 Nov 2013 10:15:02 +0100</dateCreated>
        <docs>http://www.test.com</docs>
    </head>
    <body>
        <outline title="Title1"/>
        <outline title="Title2" />
    </body> 
</opml>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for an *element* called `title` - but it's actually an *attribute*. The same code would fail on desktop too. You want:

```
title = (string)el.Attribute("title")
```

It's not really clear why you need an anonymous type here - you could just use:

```
var titles = doc.Descendants("outline")
                .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("title"));
```

(You can do this with a query expression, but personally I wouldn't - query expressions are great for complex queries, but when you're just filtering or projecting they add more fluff than they save.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. It work in my console project, not in my portable class library. Any ideas?

Comment: @Matapolo: If it's the same XML in both cases, it should be absolutely fine. You haven't told us anything about *how* it doesn't work. Do you get a compile-time failure? An exception at execution time? No matches? Where are you loading the data from?

Comment: I get no exception. In my Console Project I get a tiles object with an result overview. In my Portable class library I miss this result overview. In both projects I load the xml from the same location.

Comment: @Matapolo: Well you need to do some diagnostic checking, as the problem could be somewhere completely different. Debug through the code to work out where you do have data and where you don't. The LINQ to XML code here is fine though.

Comment: fwiw, I believe the `var titles...` line is missing an end parens after `("title")` -- would've edited, but need to change 6 chars.